# For any integers $a,b,c$, if $a+b+c=0$, then $a,b$, and $c$ are not all odd integers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove or disprove the claim below from the definition of even and odd integers.

For any integers $a,b,c$, if $a+b+c=0$, then $a,b,$ and $c$ are not all odd integers

For this problem I set up the three variables into three different definitions, $A=(2k+1)$, $B=(2j+1)$, $C=(2l+1)$. Because the sum of integers is an integer we can do $k+j+l=t$, which when simplified would equal $2t+3=0$.

I was given some hints, like this problem should be proved and not disproved, as well you can use the contrapositive to find a solution. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Hint:  What type of number do you get when adding three odd numbers?  What type of number is zero (odd or even)?

Comment: And did you try to solve the equation $2t+3=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already solved the problem. Since $2t+3=0$ has no solution when $t$ is an integer ($2t$ is even and 3 is odd), then the statement is proved.